# Is it possible to create event emitter which does not own its subscriptions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, weak-references, eventemitter

Consider we have some system's module (M) and event emitter (E) which provides some updates required by M.
When M subscribes to E it passes callback function (F) to E. At that point E would have reference to F and F would have reference to M (E → F → M). It means that M cannot be garbage collected because of event emitter. But conceptually, when M becomes unreferenced from across the system, it does not require any updates from E, so E should not prevent it from being garbage collected.

In today's JavaScript subscription model it is solved by returning explicit disposer (DF) which is a function that do unsubscription for that particular subscription. But I think that's bad for two reasons. First, it breaks natural rule of JavaScript: when something is not accessible by references that thing becomes garbage collected. Second, disposer is an additional reference. So, now DF references E, so not only E prevents M from gc, but vice versa as well (M → DF → E and E → F → M).

It seemes that this is a good place to use weak references. However, I cannot figuire out how to build event emitter on top of WeakMap or WeakSet.
Even if you put subscriptions in weak container, you still need some hard references to take them out when you need to emit. This completely nullifies benefits of weak containers!

My best idea is a hypothetical «WeakSet which supports iteration». In addition to usual API: `add`, `has` and `delete` such object should have `forEachWeak`, which works just usual forEach and grants temporary owning over iterated objects. If user would not extract such objects into other hard ref container (like Array) this does not break weakness of references and still allow to iterate over. In case of event emitter, such emitter would have an ability to emit updates to subsctiptions without having them permanently referenced.

So, is it possible to build non-owning event emitter in this or any other manner?

Comment: Maybe. Do it and I'll update my answer to 'yes'. :D  I'm still curious about it, do you have you encountered a problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But conceptually, when M becomes unreferenced from across the system, it does not require any updates from E

That depends. This only works if M is entirely passive. As soon as you want to use M to actually *do* something, you need it to get the updates regardless whether anything else references it or not. Keeping the subscription alive by storing M in a global variable (?) and unsubscribing by trying to get it garbage-collected (which is not deterministic) is pretty hard. An explicit disposer on the other hand is clear and simple.

> I cannot figuire out how to build event emitter on top of WeakMap or WeakSet.

This is not possible. WeakMap/WeakSet are [ephemerons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeron) actually, they do not provide [weak references](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-weakrefs).

Comment: > Keeping the subscription alive by storing M in a global variable (?)
In fact, yes. In any application M is either a subsystem of other M* (referenced by hard ref) or a top-level entity (and is global indeed). When subsystems is not accessible by ref they naturally garbage collected. And hypothetic "weak emitter" will lose reference to M instantly when it is not accessible from top level M*'s. So, unsubscribing still be deterministic, instant and without disposer (and gc will follow later).

Comment: But I assess your notion on disposer's explicitness. My only thought that this requirement to explicitly unsubscribe from anything may be just a consequence of lacking weak emitter. If such APIs would be based on weak emitter, unsubscribing would follow the same rules just as losing reference to subsystem.

Comment: "*In any application M is either a subsystem of other M* (referenced by hard ref) or a top-level entity (and is global indeed)*" - not in my experience of js applications, no. For example in a standard nodejs http server, the main script will create a server object and register it (or its method forming a closure over the object) to handle request events from the event loop. The object is not stored anywhere (in a global variable), what keeps it alive is only the reference from the event loop.

Comment: contd'. You might be able to pull this off for entire static "subsystems" (I'm thinking of singleton-like service objects) e.g. by exporting them from their respective modules, with the module system as a global service registry; although it's pointless for those to be weekly referenced if they are static (staying around for the entire application lifetime) anyway.

Comment: contd'. I don't think it will work with dynamically created listeners (objects that want to be notified) at all - those normally are referenced only from the emitters they registered with. If these were weak,  it wouldn't work. And if you'd hard-ref them from static modules, you'd create memory leaks - or you would have to explicitly manage them (delete their hardrefs), in which case you could go back to explicit disposers (or event unsubscription) as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I mostly agree with you that M would need some ref to E. But having ref which is a disposer and having ref which is just an owning indicator is a slightly different things. Disposer must be explicitly called, while owning ref would be gc'd when M itself gc'd and this would trigger subscription disposal.

Such event emitter still can attach disposer logic via ephemerons. In fact, both M and E can attach desired destructor logic via it. Considering current state of things this is just a speculation. But it can be a way to do it in future.